# Como comparar dos objetos en POO en C++

Tags: c++, poo

Estoy intentando diseñar mi programa, pero tengo una duda. Supongamos que tengo una clase llamada vendedor que tiene como metodo una funcion que calcula las ventas de todo el año y previamente las ventas por mes fueron ingresadas por el usuario.
En el main yo creo 2 objetos: vendedor 1 y vendedor 2.
¿Como hago para saber que vendedor ganó mas en el año?
No sabría como comparar los metodos de cada objeto, hablando de sintaxis. Pense en algo asi como:

```
if (v1.total() > v2.total())
{
...
}
```

Pero no me funciono :/

Comment: por favor, edita la pregunta y añade algo más de información. Como la implementación de la definición y la implementación de la función `total` y por qué no te funcionó (no te dio el resultado correcto, error de compilación, ...). Lo ideal es presentar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de la sobrecarga de los operadores de comparacion con funciones amigas (friend), lo cual permite plicar los operadores directamente sobre nuestros objetos.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*======== Declaracion Vendedor ========*/

class Vendedor{
    friend bool operator==(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    friend bool operator!=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    friend bool operator>(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    friend bool operator<(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    friend bool operator>=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    friend bool operator<=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2);
    int valor_;
public:
    Vendedor(int valor) : valor_{valor}{}
};

/*======== Funcion principal ========*/

int main(){
    Vendedor v1(10), v2(20);

    if(v1 > v2){
        cout<<"vendedor 1 es mayor\n";
    }else if(v1 < v2){
        cout<<"vendedor 2 es mayor\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"son iguales\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

/*======== Definicion Vendedor ========*/

bool operator==(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ == v2.valor_;
}

bool operator!=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ != v2.valor_;
}

bool operator>(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ > v2.valor_;
}

bool operator<(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ < v2.valor_;
}

bool operator>=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ >= v2.valor_;
}

bool operator<=(const Vendedor &v1, const Vendedor &v2){
    return v1.valor_ <= v2.valor_;
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que el problema sea acerca de sobrecarga de operadores.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, debes entender en qué consiste "comparar objetos". La operación que muestras:

```
v1.total() > v2.total()
```

**NO COMPARA** los objetos `v1` y `v2` si no que compara lo que sea que devuelven las funciones `total` de ambos objetos.

Si la función miembro `total` devuelve un tipo aritmético (por ejemplo `int`), podrás comparar ambos retornos directamente y si realmente dicha función "calcula las ventas de todo el año" entonces tu código ya es correcto.

Comment: Entiendo, pero como harias tu a nivel SINTAXIS para saber a partir de una funcion *total( )* cual objeto tuvo mas ventas, es decir no se como implementar el if, con 2 objetos o con la funcion de ambos.

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes, si la función *total()* calcula las ventas de todo el año, entonces tu código ya es correcto para el objetivo que buscas.